# How to fetch all comments of a G+ post through a URL parameter?

Tags: google-plus

After some random number of comments, G+ shows only a selection of the comments often leaving out the most interesting ones.

I was hoping the "?sfc=true" parameter (that G+ [occassionally](https://plus.google.com/u/0/108426155215159556558/posts/V2YJC34WoLX?sfc=true) [inserts](https://plus.google.com/+FiftyOneFifty/posts/UcSq8NJPpNr?sfc=true) in [links](https://plus.google.com/103048102370590502519/posts/bRA29Qe92Vi?sfc=true)) would show them all but it seems to have no function at all, at least [none of my G+ peeps seemed to know](https://plus.google.com/+JeroenPluimers/posts/XVXwgx1Ee7E).

How can I (in either G+ classic or G+ "new") automatically load all comments in a thread without having to click on any link?